# Why does my C program close early?

Tags: c

I am having a very confusing problem right now. I wrote a test program for myself, but sometimes after I input Crtl+C, which is what I assume to be the EOF, the program closes early without running through some more commands below the While Loop I wanted it to cancel from.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char message[140];
    char* p = message;
     int count;
int i = 0;
    int charGT;
    while((charGT=getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        message[i] = charGT;
        i++;
        printf("%d" , i);
    }
    printf("next");
    count = strlen(p);
    printf("%d", count);
    printf("after");
    return (0);
}
```

Inputting "asd\n^C" will cause my program to end early. "next" or "after" will not be printed
My theory is that somehow, the \n is causing the program to step out of the loop for a moment, and then Crtl+C is exiting the program, but I don't know how that would work.

Comment: On *-nix, `ctrl-C` sends SIGINT to the foreground process.  That is, it kills your program.

Comment: The EOF character varies, depending on your operating system. You have to watch out for that one. Windows, Unix and Linux might operate slightly different.

Comment: Oh! I see. So doing a quick google, looks like Crtl+Z is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the break command and will send an interrupt signal to your application. The default handler will cause this to exit the process.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the EOF command you are looking for.

Comment: Should I have mentioned I'm running this on Windows? Crtl+D doesn't seem to do anything but add more input So far, I've only seen Crtl+C has done anything meaningful, while Ctrl+C sometimes actually proceeds down program.

Comment: Hrm... or is it Ctrl+Z? I do input catching so rarely.

Comment: Ctrl+Z, followed by carriage return.

Answer (score 3):

For running on windows, to enter EOF press **Ctrl+Z** and then press ENTER. In UNIX systems it is Ctrl+D, in Windows Ctrl+Z.

Answer (score 1):

When a program is running if you press Ctrl-c a signal is sent to abort the program and the program is aborted. However, if you want to use Ctrl-c as an input but not abort the program write one signal handler which catches the signal when you press Ctrl-c and perform the action you wanted to.